# Mortgage payoff early

Tags: mortgage

Jack gets a mortgage for his new house on Apr 1, 2022. His mortgage amount is $100,000 for 30 years and the interest rate is 4%.
His mortgage payment is due the 1st of every month.
Parts of the Amortization schedule is shown below:

[image: Pic of the payment schedule is here]

On Jan 20th, 2024, Jack wins the lottery for $49,882.59 and he immediately uses that money to pay a huge chunk of the principal. After making this huge payment, his account shows that the new principal balance is $46,834.16.

Here is the question:

When Jack makes his regular monthly payment on Feb 1st, 2024, what amount of that payment will go towards the principal? Will the amount going towards the principal be $155.03 or $320.23?

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: How does the interest accrue, daily, or monthly (on the balance the day before the payment)? and how often is the interest applied (your presented truncated payments schedule suggests monthly in arrears)?

Comment: Also assuming that there is no early repayment penalty on the mortgage?

Comment: Finally, I'm assuming you are opting to keep the repayment amount the same (and reduce the term), as opposed to reducing the monthly repayment and keeping the term the same, is this correct?

Comment: In general, whatever payment you make is first used to pay off the accrued interest; the rest is applied against the principal. There's really not enough information here to determine what the accrued interest will be.

Comment: @chepner: Some (not all) loans do let you specifically make additional payments to pay down the principal, without penalty, though you may have to be very explicit about the fact that you are doing this. That's what's being assumed in this homework question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, in the US anyway, with a mortgage loan, you can make prepayments without penalty. The payment remains the same regardless of prepayments. The amount of the payment that goes towards interest depends on the current balance.

So say that you are paying 4% interest. That means 4/12% or 1/3 of 1% per month.

If your principal on a certain date is, say, $100,000 and your payment is $500, then 1/3 of 1% of $100,000 will go to interest, or $333. The remaining $167 will go to principal.

If before the next month you make a prepayment of $40,000, then the next month your principal is only $60,000. 1/3 of 1% of $60,000 is $200, so $200 will go to interest and the remaining $300 to principal.

Generally, to change the payment amount you have to refinance the loan.

Oh, this assumes that the payment amount we're talking about is principal plus interest and doesn't include taxes or insurance.

Comment: @jcaron Oops, thanks for the spelling correction.

Comment: Prepayment, and paying down principal, are very different things. The former can almost always be done without penalty. The latter, not always, and you may have to be very explicit to keep it from being recorded as prepayment.

Comment: @keshlam Hmm, what are you saying is the difference? Any loan I've ever had, if you made a "prepayment" that reduced the principal. Perhaps there is a regional difference in the definitions?

Comment: Some loans, if you don't explicitly say it's toward the principal, just count the extra as an advance deposit to buffer against missing or late payments. Some _only_ accept prepayment rather than paying down, or charge a processing fee on paying down. Make very sure you and your lender agree on how the money will be processed; don't assume. (This may be regulated differently in other places; I would still suggest making sure it is  all explicit and in writing, and check your statements to confirm.)

Comment: @keshlam Certainly true that there's a big difference between making a payment early but which will still be processed as a regular payment, versus making a "principal only" payment. My understanding has always been that "prepayment" always refers to the second. Maybe that's not true in some countries, with some banks, etc. Also true that you should make clear your payment is being applied as you want. I once had a loan where I made a fairly substantial payment that I intended to go to principal, and the bank applied it as, I have now made my next 12 payments in advance. ...

Comment: ... Side note: When I figured out what they'd done and called the bank, they said yes, that's what they did, because you can't make principal only payments on this loan. I read them the section of the loan contract that said I could make principal only payments, "in whole or in part" "at any time". They told me that processing that "would require reissuing the note". I said okay, sorry if it's a lot of paperwork, but the contract says I can do it. They refused. The loan wasn't that big so I said fine, I paid it off and never did business with that bank again.

Comment: If it was big, you could still refinance it with a saner bank. Personally I'd have walked into the local branch, spoken to someone on the platform (ie, the bank representatives who are not tellers) and told them that their phone support is not properly trained and is going to get them in legal trouble... and asked them what to write in order to have this money processed properly.

Comment: @keshlam True. Maybe I should have. A more aggressive person might have sued them for breach of contract and yes, gotten them in big legal trouble.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a homework question, so I'm not going to give the actual numbers, but the general method to figure this out:

If the payment doesn't change after the prepayment (which is common), then you calculate the interest amount of the next payment by taking the new principal amount times the interest rate divided by 12. Then subtract that interest amount by the monthly payment to see how much goes to principal.

If the prepayment changes the payment amount (called a "reamortization", which is rare), then you'd have to reamortize the loan and can get the next principal amount fore the amortization schedule.

NOTE:

After looking more closely and considering the comments, there may be other subtleties (e.g. does the payment go to the interest accrued between Jan 1 and Jan 20?). But, given that the final question is a multiple choice, it's clear that the answer is NOT 155.03. The payment will reduce the principal to the amount originally scheduled for Apr 2042, which will restart the amortization schedule from that date forward, meaning the interest amount is  $320.23.